# How to get the profile of current user in Express

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am using MEAN Stack and mongoose. Using passport for authentication. I want to get the currently logged in user and display his details. For example if I am logged in and if I go to the profile page I want to get my details. There were only few resources on the internet.

> Login.js (passport and routes are here)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var passport = require('passport');

var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var User = require('../models/user');

var ConnectRoles = require('connect-roles');


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

res.render('Login', { title: 'Login' });
});

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {

    done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {

    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {

    done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use("/", new LocalStrategy(

     function(username, password, done) {

        User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {

            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false,
                 { message: "No user has that username!" });
            }
            user.checkPassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {

            if (err) { return done(err); }
                if (isMatch) {

                    return done(null, user);
                } else {
                    return done(null, false,
                 { message: "Invalid password." });
            }
        });
    });
}));

router.use(function(req, res, next) {

    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;

    res.locals.errors = req.flash("error");

    res.locals.infos = req.flash("info");
    next();
});

router.post("/", passport.authenticate("/", {

    successRedirect: "/SubmitSurvey",
    failureRedirect: "/",
    session: false,
    failureFlash: true
}));


router.get("/AdminDatabase", function(req, res) {

   res.render('AdminDatabase', { title: 'AdminDatabase' });

 });


router.get('/CreateSurvey', function(req, res, next) {

  res.render('CreateSurvey', { title: 'CreateSurvey' });

});


router.get('/SubmitSurvey', function(req, res, next) {

  res.render('SubmitSurvey', { title: 'SubmitSurvey' });

});


router.get('/profile', function(req, res, next) {

  res.render('profile', { title: 'profile' });

});


router.get("/Logout", function(req, res) {

    req.logout();

    res.redirect("/");
});

module.exports = router;
```

How can I do this in nodejs

Comment: ``req.user``. But please search before asking, it's a trivial question and it has been asked a trillion times already.

Answer (score 6):

It's on the `req.user` object

```
router.get('/profile', function(req, res, next) {

    //here it is
    var user = req.user;

    //you probably also want to pass this to your view
    res.render('profile', { title: 'profile', user: user });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

**passport** fills the `req.user` object with the current user through middlewares pipelines so you can extract it from there.

Answer (score 3):

As Alex said, you may explicitly pass some variable (e.g. your `req.user`) when calling `res.render`:

```
router.get('/profile', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('profile', { title: 'profile', user: req.user });
});
```

Instead, maybe you'd like some variables (like that `req.user`) to be accessible in *all* calls to `res.render` without bothering to specify them every time? In that case, you can use [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals), e.g. by adding this middleware:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.locals.user = req.user;
  next();
});
```

And finally, for completeness -- in both of the approaches above, the variable `user` is available for you in the view. For example, if you're using a [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) template, you may now do something like:

```
if user
  p Hello, #{user.id}, good to see you!
else
  p Please log in...
```