# Get current Active Director user name in javascript/ajax/json from a Meteor App

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, meteor, active-directory

I am already connected in an organisation in an Active Directory (LDAP).  After that, I want to connect with Meteor to a MongoDB etc...  I have to **get the user name (Me in occurrence who is already connected)** from Active Directory. But first of all, how do I get my user in js. or ajax,json call in meteor.js(node.js or others?).

I have look a lot at different things, like if you are in server side with asp.net you can do this : [Page.User.Identity.Name](https://forums.asp.net/t/1045923.aspx?How+to+get+the+Windows+username+of+the+currently+logged+in+user+to+pass+to+Active+Directory+in+C+) So maybe create a web service that return your user?

Would

```
<script language="javascript">var username   =
    '<HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>';
   </script>
```

work?

But if I follow the link it explain it's for Razor.
[How to get the user's username in my intranet web application in a windows network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359648/how-to-get-the-users-username-in-my-intranet-web-application-in-a-windows-netwo)

Maybe the solution is to get an API with Meteor to do call json to get username like JSonAuth? Or to use node.js with passport.js but now new version of Meteor use oAuth it seems..
or to call the IIS Server to know the current user?

[How to get the profile of current user in node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468105/how-to-get-the-profile-of-current-user-in-node-js/41468587)

Comment: User information is only available server-side, which can inject that information into the client-side code that's sent to the browser. What framework are you using on the server? (.NET, NodeJS, etc.)

Comment: It's Node.js with come along Meteor.js.

Comment: Maybe this Library will work , will try it : https://www.npmjs.com/package/username

Comment: You're going to need an AD package for Meteor, something like https://atmospherejs.com/rmbrich/meteor-activedirectory perhaps?

Comment: I want to know what my current user is...  I want to connect to the AD of Meteor but I don't have a form for login and password because I am connected... so if my user don't exist in Meteor I create it after etc... but first of all how to get my user on my machine.